# Recyclerview multi view items with button

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I want to create a multi-view on Recylcerview by clicking the button(different view for each button). how to write code in Adapter Class or Condition to view it differently.

this is my code.
Adapter Class

public class TripAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TripAdapter.TripHolderOne> {
private List trips = new ArrayList<>();

```
@NonNull
@Override
public TripHolderOne onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.trip_item, parent, false);

    return new TripHolderOne(itemView);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TripHolderOne holder, int position) {
    Trip currentTrip = trips.get(position);
    holder.textViewTripTitle.setText(currentTrip.getTripTitle());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(currentTrip.getDescription());
    holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(currentTrip.getPriority()));
    holder.textViewStartDateTime.setText(currentTrip.getStartDateTime());

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return trips.size();
}

public void setTrips(List<Trip> trips) {
    this.trips = trips;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public Trip getTripAt(int position) {
    return trips.get(position);
}


class TripHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textViewTripTitle;
    private TextView textViewDescription;
    private TextView textViewPriority;
    private TextView textViewStartDateTime;

    public TripHolderOne(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTripTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
        textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_priority);
        textViewStartDateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_start_date_time);


    }
}
```

MainActivity Class

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final TripAdapter adapter = new TripAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    tripViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(TripViewModel.class);
    tripViewModel.getAllTrips().observe(this, new Observer<List<Trip>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Trip> trips) {
            adapter.setTrips(trips);
        }
    });
```

And inside MainActivity also have function onActivityResult.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == ADD_TRANSPORTATION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String title = data.getStringExtra(AddTripActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String description = data.getStringExtra(AddTripActivity.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION);
        int priority = data.getIntExtra(AddTripActivity.EXTRA_PRIORITY, 1);
        String startDate = data.getStringExtra(AddTripActivity.EXTRA_START_DATE);
        String startTime = data.getStringExtra(AddTripActivity.EXTRA_START_TIME);
        String startDateTime = data.getStringExtra(AddTripActivity.EXTRA_START_DATE_TIME);
        Log.d("TAG", "Text from MainActivity2" + data.getStringExtra("text"));


        Trip trip = new Trip(title, description, priority, startDate,startTime,startDateTime);
        tripViewModel.insert(trip);

        Toast.makeText(this, "trip saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     
    }
```

Comment: Could you please exaplain what you mean with  multi view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed When I click a different button I have pass data and show to the MainActivity in different Cardview.